# Complicated recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I would like to know if the following recurrence relation is solvable

\begin{equation}
(\alpha_{1}n^{2}+\beta_{1}n+\gamma_{1})\ c(n+1)+(\alpha_{0}n^{2}+\beta_{0}n+\gamma_{0})\ c(n)+(\alpha_{-1}n^{2}+\beta_{-1}n+\gamma_{-1})\ c(n-1)=0
\end{equation}

where $\alpha$'s,$\beta$'s and $\gamma$'s are constants.

I am particularly interested in the case where $\alpha_{1}=0$ and $\gamma_{-1}=0$. Moreover, $\beta_{1}=\alpha_{-1}$ and $\gamma_{1}=\beta_{-1}$ therefore the recurrence relation reduces to

\begin{equation}
(\beta_{1}n+\gamma_{1})\ c(n+1)+(\alpha_{0}n^{2}+\beta_{0}n+\gamma_{0})\ c(n)+n(\beta_{1}n+\gamma_{1})\ c(n-1)=0
\end{equation}

I am hoping that I could find a similar recurrence relation for some special functions such as Hypergeometric functions or generalized Hypergeometric functions or Heun functions. Also, I know that some orthogonal polynomials such as Hahn, Krawtchoul and Charlier polynomials have three term recurrence relations. However, I have not been successful to match any of them with my recurrence relation.

Comment: Any chance you tried applying the z-transform?

Comment: Yes I have tried the z-transform. The resulting differential equation is very complicated. 2nd order with z-dependent coefficients up to $z^3$

Comment: Ah, right. Just checking the obvious strategy.